# Mysterious error with Google Fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I am trying to use Google fonts in [this](http://www.codetocode-developments.com/t-one/) website. The link is in the head, if you click it the result is the correct. In the CSS, the font-family is the correct, but the font I am seen in my screen is not the correct.

This is the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="options-google-fonts" title="google-fonts" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300%7CMontserrat&amp;subset=latin&amp;v=1399056353" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

And the CSS:

```
.caption-wrap .line-2, .caption-wrap .line-3, .caption-wrap .line-5 a, .navbar-nav>li>a, .service-wrap .service-btm a {
font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

Nobody can tell me if is there a problem with this?

Comment: Where is there a problem? It's displaying correctly in Chrome

Comment: Only Hardy boys can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link was generated by Redux Options Framework. The problem seems to occurs only on Chrome  in Windows 8.

The problem fixes deleting the title attribute.

Comment: `title` is not a valid attribute for a `link` tag, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet to link the CSS, it's done the way Google recommends to link their fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: The result page of the link is same so it would work

Answer (score 0):

You put the stylesheet `<link>` element inside the `<body>`.  It should be in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Chrome is concerned, a page served as HTTPS should not be calling a resource served as HTTP. Chrome isn't picky about when things are the other way around, so it will happily retrieve an HTTPS resource via a page served as HTTP.
Solutions

Match the protocols

Make sure you always call the https version of your Google Webfont URL.  For example:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300%7CMontserrat&amp;subset=latin&amp;v=1399056353'
 rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all">
```

Comment: Hard-coding the scheme is bad advice. Using `//:` is preferred as it will use the same scheme matching the page's URL.